# wonky problems with bootstrap -> rows not consistent width only on large screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this weird problem with bootstrap and rows. It only seems to happen in the LG view which is greater than 1200px. For some reason random rows are not conforming to the full amount they should(in this case 1140px) and instead are smaller.

I am including a few pictures to show exactly the issue I am talking about to see if I can figure out what is going on. Any help would be appreciated.

If i make the width smaller to simulate a smaller screen everything works without issue.

```
https://s21.postimg.org/8i0w6wtpz/Screen_Shot_2016_09_18_at_7_22_08_PM.png
https://s22.postimg.org/xr3ekeyf5/Screen_Shot_2016_09_18_at_7_23_09_PM.png
https://s22.postimg.org/dkzwlj2rl/Screen_Shot_2016_09_18_at_7_23_28_PM.png


<section class="inner">
<div class="container portfolio-container">
<h2>PORTFOLIO</h2>
<div class="prcnr" ng-repeat="port in portfolio">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <a rel="{{port._id}}" class="fancybox" href="images/uploads/{{ port.main_image }}">
                <img src="images/uploads/{{ port.main_image }}" alt="" class="main_portfolio_image img-responsive">
            </a>
            <div class="hidden">
                    <a rel="{{port._id}}" ng-repeat="image in port.images" class="fancybox" href="images/uploads/{{image}}">
                        <img src="images/uploads/{{image}}" alt="">
                    </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 port-txt">
            <h4><b>{{ port.title }}</b></h4>
            <p ng-bind-html="port.description"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Custom CSS Pertaining to this code :

```
.portfolio-container h4 {
font-size: 22.5px;
}

.portfolio-container .port-txt p {
font-size: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
.main_portfolio_image {
    width: 570px;
    height: 385px;
}
}
```

Comment: put some code or make a JSFIDDLE

Comment: code posted in question

Comment: Do you create any extra css for this section ??if yes then provide the css also..  And in your code there is no /section closing tag. Maybe you have more then 1 row in this section.

Comment: Try class container-fluid and see if any changes appears

Answer (score 0):

those picture are not slimier to your code. 
there is 2 col-lg-6 column I found where one column contain a hidden filed. that's not a problem. And you are using bootstrap so you don't need to set media query for image . Just simply use img-responsive and set the image with a min-width of 100% like and add container-fluid in html part

```
       img.img-responsive{
           min-width:100% !important;
        }
```

[image: this what I get from your Code.. Just add the image from my site]